# How to apply eventListener to all classes?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have been working on dropdown from scratch for learning JS (please don't mind about the look). I have managed to make the first element work, and show the result (clicking on dropdown element and display it to dropdown). But as soon as i have added second dropdown, the second dropdown does not work and i don't know why. I have target classes, and are the same in both. 
I am a beginner with JS, so please explain on basic level so i can understand :).

https://codepen.io/jernejt/pen/erYpLa

```js
let dropdownSelection = document.querySelector(".dropdown-selection");
let dropdownInput = document.querySelector(".dropdown-input");
let dropdownItem = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-item");

dropdownInput.addEventListener("click", function(){
    dropdownSelection.classList.toggle("active");
});

for (let i = 0; i < dropdownItem.length; i++){
    dropdownItem[i].addEventListener("click", function (){
        dropdownInput.textContent = dropdownItem[i].textContent;
        dropdownSelection.classList.toggle("active"); 
    });
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-input {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 44px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-selection {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
  top: 44px;
  left: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-selection .dropdown-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown .active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
 <span class="dropdown-input">Select item</span>
 <ul class="dropdown-selection">
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 2</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 3</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 4</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 5</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
 <span class="dropdown-input">Select item</span>
 <ul class="dropdown-selection">
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 2</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 3</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 4</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 5</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please add your your code

Comment: `.toggle("active"); ` is jQuery, not JS

Comment: @Justinas it is available on `classList`. check here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp

Comment: @user2762414 have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49892879/6804958) answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how I would have done it.

What's happening here is, Add click `eventlisteners` to each element i-e `(.dropdown-input)` and  as in your `DOM` structure  `ul` is very next element to this, you can just use `nextElementSibling` to add active class to the clicked element. And yeah, before adding active class, you can remove active classes if there is any. Just to give it more user friendly look.

Here is the snippet

```js
var dpds = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-input');

dpds.forEach(function (x) {
  x.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-selection').forEach(function (e) {
    if(x.nextElementSibling !== e)
      return e.classList.remove("active");
    });
    x.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-input {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 44px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-selection {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
  top: 44px;
  left: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-selection .dropdown-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown .active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
 <span class="dropdown-input">Select item</span>
 <ul class="dropdown-selection">
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 2</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 3</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 4</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 5</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
 <span class="dropdown-input">Select item</span>
 <ul class="dropdown-selection">
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 2</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 3</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 4</li>
   <li class="dropdown-item">Item 5</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet shows how to add event listeners to multiple dom elements having same class.

```js
//new syntax 
Array
  .from(document.getElementsByClassName("foo"))
  .forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", 
       f =>   document.getElementById("bar").innerText = f.target.innerText ));


//old syntax
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("foo")).forEach(function(foo){
  foo.addEventListener('mouseover', function(evt){
    document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = evt.target.innerHTML + "(mouseover)"; 
});
});
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <p>dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <p>consectetur adipiscing elit,</p>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="bar">
 ...
</div>
```